# Text to JSON formatting

Tags: java, javascript, json, parsing, gson

I'm wondering, can I have text like this:

```
ps:mandatory' child of Input command functions
Properties

ps:Source:
    f47437

ps:Created:
    2010-09-03T11:38:02.629Z

ps:ChangedBy:
    F47437

ps:Changed:
    2011-09-07T07:51:10.864Z
```

In JSON format. The problem is there ..that the file includes tens of thousands of that text type and they're like tree family. And my point is to convert it to JSON saving the same tree logic. I just wanted to ask for my own knowledge.

Comment: Why is this tagged both Java and Javascript?

Comment: Because I'm doing something like java to javascript conversation,I'll remove it if it's problem? It will take long time to explain what my exactly problem is..for now that formatting is all I need.

Comment: So you want a library or something that can create nice formatted JSON? If so, what language are you programming in?

Comment: Javascript or Java,doesn't matter which one :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
{
    "ps:mandatory": "Properties",
    "ps:Source:": "f47437",
    "ps:Created:": "2010-09-03T11:38:02.629Z",
    "ps:ChangedBy:": "F47437",
    "ps:Changed:": "2011-09-07T07:51:10.864Z"
}
```

It's important to remember that JSON is *unordered* so you will most likely lose the order of the tags when storing it in JSON. If order is important, consider another file format.

---

The following code will turn your data above into JSON. Compiles and works:

```
import org.json.*;
public class CreateMyJSON
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String testData = "ps:mandatory\nProperties\n\nps:Source:\n    f47437\n\nps:Created:\n    2010-09-03T11:38:02.629Z\n\nps:ChangedBy:\n    F47437\n\nps:Changed:\n    2011-09-07T07:51:10.864Z\n\n";
        CreateMyJSON cmj = new CreateMyJSON();
        System.out.println(cmj.getJSONFromString(testData));
        }

    public String getJSONFromString(String theData)
    {   
        JSONObject jso = new JSONObject();
        //no error checking, but replacing double returns
        //to make this simpler
        String massagedData = theData.replaceAll("\n\n", "\n");
        String[] splits = massagedData.split("\n");
        for(int i = 0; i < splits.length; i++)
        {
            jso.put(splits[i].trim(), splits[++i].trim());
        }

        return jso.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well something like this.I should say there's way to order the JSON format,there are a lot of examples especially with hypertree.js projects,but my file is kinda big..and I was curious if there is easier way to parse it to JSON ..because to make it done now I should use regex,pattern etc..

Comment: How big is "kinda big"? If the entire file is as regular as the bit you posted in your example it would be trivial to convert it to JSON using simple Java string manipulation and even if it's a few thousand lines it should process pretty quickly.

Comment: can you give me more details ..what exactly would be that string manipulation? It is regular like the code below and there are around 30 000 lines.

Comment: I'm going out for a bit, when I return I'll post some sample code to show you how to do it (if someone else doesn't beat me to the punch).

Comment: See the code I just posted and let me know if it does what you want.